# Equirectangular to Cubic with point to point mapping?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, projection, panoramas

I need to convert a panorama in equirectangular projection to 6 cubic faces and then to spherical projection and back, however I need to keep a track of how each point is mapped in each projection like

> Equirectangular Point(x,y) <---> Cubic face Point (x, y) <---> Sphere Point(x, y, z)

How can I accomplish this in C++ and OpenCV?

These transformations are required because I need to find out the good matching key-points between two such images by comparing angles between keypoints when the two panoramas, projected on a sphere, are placed side by side.

Here is the panorama:[image: A 360 degree equirectangular image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved, below is the function to convert 2d Panoramic to 3d spherical coordinates.

```
vector<int> getSphericalPoint3D(int x, int y, int cols, int rows)
{
    //introduce a radius to 
    static const int radius = 128;
    vector<int> point3D;
    // the center 
    double c_x = (double)cols / 2;
    double c_y = (double)rows / 2;

    double X = (((double)x - c_x) * CV_PI) / c_x;
    double Y = (((double)y - c_y) * CV_PI) / c_y;

    int x3D = round(radius * cos(X) * cos(Y)) + radius;
    int y3D = round(radius * cos(X) * sin(Y)) + radius;
    int z3D = round(radius * sin(X)) + radius;

    point3D = { x3D, y3D, z3D };
    return point3D;
}
```

1. The idea is to normalize 2d pixels from -Pi to Pi on both X and Y axis
2. Use the following relationship to get spherical co-ordinates

x = R * cos(x)cos(y) + R (this R is added to avoid the negative values)

y = R * cos(x)sin(y) + R

z = R * sin(x) + R

A similar transformation is used for Cubic transformation